# Dropping Temp Tables in a Wrapper Stored Procedure (SQL APS/PDW)

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have created a stored procedure that has many stored procedures inside of it , i.e. a wrapper procedure.

The procedure does not complete because there are temp tables that have the same name between the different stored procedures in the wrapper proc.

I need to find a way to drop all temp tables between stored procedures within the wrapper

Or

Have a general command to drop all temp tables at the end of each stored procedure that is within the wrapper.

The environment is Microsoft SQL APS(PDW)

Comment: Do your temp tables actually start with # or ##? Or do you have real tables that you are calling temp tables. If you have scope limited temp tables that start with #, this problem should not occur because they are dropped when the proc goes out of scope.  Please provide text of error message as well.

Answer (score 0):

This should give you the list of temp tables.Once you have the list you can select what you are creating and drop them one by one using dynamic sql.

```
select * from tempdb.sys.objects where type='U'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this to check for them in your procedure and then drop them.  This can be dangerous if other procedures are creating them and using them but are not finished with them.

```
If Object_ID('tempdb..#yourTempTable') Is Not Null 
    Drop Table #yourTempTable
```

Or to generate the drop commands you can use this:

```
 Select 'Drop table tempdb..' + Name From tempdb.sys.objects where type = 'U' and is_ms_shipped = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You have misinterpreted your error messages, whatever they might be.  I did the following.  Note that sp1 and sp2 both create a table named #t1.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp1] 
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    create table #t1(id integer);
    insert into #t1
    SELECT 1 record;

    select id from #t1;
END

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp2]

AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    create table #t1(id integer);
    insert into #t1
    SELECT 2 record;

    select id from #t1;
END
GO

alter PROCEDURE sp3

AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;     
    declare @t1 as table (id integer);

    insert into @t1
    exec sp1;
    insert into @t1
    exec sp2;

    select id from @t1;
END
GO
```

And now the big test.  This

```
exec sp3
```

returns two rows, with values of 1 and 2.